# Tessellation in 3D

Tags: algorithm

I have a set of  **Points in 3D space**.
The image below is an example:

[image]

I would like to turn these points into a surface. I just know the X,Y and Z values of the points.
For example, check out the image below, which shows a mesh of a human face generated from points in 3D space.

[image]

i googled so much but, what i found is some images and explaination
but no one has explained with practical aspect and practical example.
is there any good or best algorithms which help me to solve this problem.
Please....
Thaks...........

Comment: Your data looks like a surface with only one Z value for every X,Y. Is that true or not? If so it may make the problem easier.

Comment: i don't got you clearly but though i clear my question,  if you consider z=1 as plane then there may be many points are there in this plane with various x and y values.....  Thanks......

Comment: Is it possible to have several z-values that corespond to the same values of x and y? If you havs a point x=2, y=2 z=2. Can you also have a point x=2, y=2 z=3? (I think that gentlesea assumes that you want to plot a function z=f(x,y). This task is simpler than plotting a surface such as a spehere or a head.)

Answer (score 1):

You want to do a Delaunay-Triangulation. See example application here: http://www.geometrylab.de/VoroGlide/.

Comment: Thanks a so much after seeing this link i have hope that my problem will solve soon.....  Thank you so much...... if you have another good links than please suggest if possible ........ Thank you so much friend....

Comment: You might want to decide which programming language you take. If it is C++ you might also want to look here: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/algorithms/general/article.php/c8901. This I have not tested though. I know the theoretical background from university.

Comment: @gentlesea,  Thanks a lot..... and i currently working in C# so is there any example in C# then it would be so good........Thanks in advance.....

Comment: @gentlesea,   hello gentlesea i found that  Delaunay-Triangulation algorithms is for points in 2D space. in my case points are in 3D space....so i think Delaunay-Triangulation will no help me...

Comment: there are delaynay-Triangulation for 3D space. there is a good toolkit www.vtk.org there are a lot of various algorithms and you can vizualize it. Here is the link for delaunay3D class documentation http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDelaunay3D.html. Also you can read the source and convert source to C#